# MediaPlayer and AudioTrack don't output the same sound

Tags: java, android, audio, signal-processing

I have a wav file called 'new.wav' and I want to play it via MediaPlayer and AudioTrack in android:

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String fileName = "new.wav";
File f = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);
byte[] b = null;

try {
    b=this.readFile(f);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.i("123"," "+"length is "+b.length);
truncated=new byte[b.length-44];
truncated=Arrays.copyOf(b, b.length-44);
at=new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 48000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, truncated.length /* 1 second buffer */, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
at.write(truncated, 0, truncated.length);
at.play();

mp = new MediaPlayer();

try {
    mp.setDataSource(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    mp.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After having tried both methods, I found that their sound is not the same, the AudioTrack is not outputing the original sound in the wav file. I think my sample rate is fine, can someone help me with this issue? THank you!

Comment: I think the audiotrack is playing it with lower frequency. BTW

Comment: looks like if i change the option to AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, it produces the same output. dont know why though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments above, the problem is the choice of channels.